# Decode Access Token getting from frontend IOS application to fetch user information using Okta and Node JS

Tags: ios, node.js, jwt, access-token, okta

I am trying to decode the access token at the backend which i receive from frontend using okta jwt verifier. I am not sure about which type of token i am getting as it does not seems to be JWT token.Login module has developed by some other company and client is not aware about the Encoded mechanism.So the access token we are getting is of the form:

The entire response that i am receiving at login -

success({
  "scope": "userinfo offline_access",

"token_type": "Bearer",

"expires_in": 3600,

"access_token": "**CfDJ8G7oFS712aJJkUnWhDsiXlVRL4XtxRzsNbl6up_LvGbZlZtW1RwE9pRxsVC73MT6I-r7Wvj7rVsb-jp6hghJYrHLrk9KqEmUDOtHDhE63edAGnPm3WntjEL_dQyanOXHb7aiSWFeLDVak_tV0lH6DSMCbpvy-6Cr5TPmCBHRUZybOQWYl36aidrskEvZACuPy3AvfkSCnIcFIjDuh7JSk7IU_LPZzI42Pa-O2-6V4LGf6pqtdLmO1KZIPD6gtOJn7Fidk_SDOxW74OuPakBLCf_7kQAwV1qB8lyG_Dcz_fL5qK45T9iqtyf_nB6rtwvdj07rzqgGGQ6T_JAUOAo745xoF7gnl-hIZ8pxu9OPgGdC8ymFqSneFuOhv2QZty6OMVc_ORlqoW3XTtntmBuEBSYUKnYmb4n-JAkg_cAvj-lvugxBrlHJqFKUabPbZC6_MWsMabonq0IAI_-CP7OcFcjRXGgyqgTtyYYU8UfbsYhJtp7eYyQSd_WNebiEuYOQoqrCigY7XzHoCV97YQ1TuotpuLFtHDzXc1gi_1DAozrira2LCh2DOrbAsmucKwun-G5pi2VbjFwTLknbz9vcfgrfxhq6AD9P1SALG2UtPgBMoMJ0ZW4VyEJ83NCAqaOrhHMuNrPEwdB3vrEqydJerH0xbL3Z8NtE54qu_vN6IGt8yO1SkQFNibui3FBG8Aq26zsjMusC9AlXX1EMqyLK5w9VzdbzEbeY7T5od9gYqMUR_5N1Xpr8vNKuMAanqNBHqkHBsOTgumSluSoa4BKHPS4eSvImo8ip2siKRkk3c348XqR_kIGToyuElROpVZuZ1PfTTp0tYpneCfKIHwtymt11gq-vZ-3dPjOSGQU-W5zemFAyhrEv-6NSQfGI-vi4rsWPr6fpeGgiEA3CkBUanbrXbsM3-48cHFkj0NkG3z1bTGqoAHmwP9Fub8-EhQDpNd74znYyi75Un_OjbLb2pvZ8Vp6ewRClaCEjXL44_7SOWyQ-uNnjIS_wlJ01WzRj6Nj9VNTlhYktBhi0LbUIYiaRrazCF671pc3KxYmLQzh8tLw-x-pG5UHLQNnId6YgbNL9vXi8B7NaKOMMI7ip46mO32rSxS4TE2cWjxUFeDMoRxN3XaZ9TLANvrvDpdZVSRyTpqHVmjk5Lfnj8GAUG4FY9NWYHsGLwXnT3Nn2GAgKjjVRTpUoSuXrqDCzM0fXDRAFPZ8SLe5YviG6_O4AtqGGzqj7wUUcotkwrH4WU7xVcDBip4L8yEudNCPpQkLOs0tdU5qysO8pAyVgJ89taBWeCB3VkKTdi9VXgOpUjg_wJU2eAez_xVkf3qgovk80vivhIrjRVAh0vyPVmYWwF1uwsjzx_w3_3HYspbPIC7KSpmxaMdiTg6a2wJtimdo_wmhNIJhe-EY60VG0Hlnmv6kuiakXqhyuFLl-XC97TrZL**",

"refresh_token": "**CfDJ8G7oFS712aJJkUnWhDsiXlUEOo0WAwIjVHVFeMiNBX4jl9mIJhwKW2uzS4OaiwhddF9LBbKOWkGaKw8vNynImRV0wJmHpp8U6iWP3UIY29s6rD65_iwrsPYfiBnrGUfusTCPRLG43Px1VQIgsBGhSGkys8t89IlKFLn7ec48Hkj8SKE0gAU6MhncTCZcyuuPzy-ip_u7OSwfxVd495qcpsnTbcxU2kfITyoVOl25NBXKYdaemMoqznEN4DMgfXNStNNTXgl0P6W6ag7frCVaiQSd9vHS9wohmLVmGH6-jyZ7Fad7LRIKMZgtMCONssGE2b8Bi0FhCJsKwYelFRcfR2Ox4IRBz0yTe8bQ3qfgYxcO4DzP9IT6kg0gZODNIi-CfhtOufMGUS5ZW6jTKXz5JFjF7JpwlY3vZokIWtu-HWrLsrFYUBGvBFxE6vWMuJ9GKv1B8Av85BKilWe3t8ND24-zDj0LIl7eZGmVa596VhoB7uepL4rQQb22f4Qagcw3NwUUfwl9Y4F-nguYZZxFNeESJItJ5Zlk6QUMaOQytMqCbxIB1ZuO_9-1qpo4EFv5rvFUPyMsU6o0Z78jytUVipgWu91Uzy0EDa6Qq9HgmYKykocxpMgerfKWo4W1z1qiCdjQ5g5n-Vzv50ZfD18HiCk1F3viiUEvMFUE3JmXVJ_YVoO0170LFryhSpTCsgx-UxiePKRXmhTheeOGxMNbhYCI6TXhgknesYFibdbds-3oLe135B0RJ3wG3_-NuEVLARWsPabYwF8puHIpHMH6io0oC4TcerOL-HfyI0CfvxNMRHydGQhVwSk72ja7yi0I_1BnnKop2UMtt_xGfkUkUlNXfJkvXAigUC77IphlfnMoQ5WZMWj-sPyHR-180z4OkeS8vXAwGxDFYI2Cl0Dc1XQXsbxQq98zxFWh7oni4EUxeb5eLoiK_zTcmQsq-4uq_W-PRGRS-QlkiHWKMvNykMWhYBSxpzHORfG4RRE4fVbdWbHMU0gh2d74mbXCJanw-ViYXdO2u3zh-k8oMbmHp2nNw3SBsMcCZPE2pOkdNlxGJTF1B9pS9BfTlxc60uF7JC9u57UqjGa-bA_xVOnvdB72JtVjtpV4eU9OWczfkCNlnWt7q4QBskVpI7zMuQfFhWaa4lbilrKuUwl1O057qvcP2cm800qeT3FGgebIXnfFmUEXCA4K28nvPa50yHXxK8nS6iKsPZSKSXaDenyCLjejxd4IyrYj0B02GXJLq7SmpZVYaQRoUq8AAawI0OUxoD31jj_bR_IdComt1Fljiz0y8BZxH74_sYl0gNTV1o6tDOEbE_2BeX7fiTJtMOk33W5kqeqsHA9stPUk8rZyOLSoK3u1tLAr0wZfnWSMw6GXu1gtG8UKuYD5SkqtnjPSOKZkvgS2D_aLKaBdNPqwoWSlqsLETiu2XbnDrunaSpRyIddYnHG9_r9zfSzXHYVEIjkJc9ix_V3tFjDOHkhi6Jg1qtYyG3l-BWGODo0uyduYKDoVJ9hjHdAlFy7gp87iE_LW-LN56IcziAFfPyV5cqYyQ571UFFET4kVTK3ypRrkEgPwwaGvj8Mm0IptJDpXOD6_wJm92YGgwlkGFsly1girz9YcOZpXfzo7KU1-s_zxSPLSx15eRvKU8FRblcSZZI1oGR8x3h1Cw-3dS3PkPkeidTVwN9In_VDWx4RgR6uwt6yxQJ49ZMKufvnv2DaZVr2pzSuj9a4BtNw7c_sIohE-Or8GbaksncXfD_JGMXR28NsDGLaH-uLJGPdGDK0YzO3bdkqAg4RQo1QHDCLY6X11pY3jIVhsvtLZzwrR3K81-Ff_QwDPBV0D8RrMVnAKYvb4AOdBDXWrrO2BckrvAFqfA1R-BFTJUAOJC9KH18qN**"
},

Optional([
  AnyHashable("Pragma"): no-cache,

AnyHashable("x-amzn-remapped-connection"): keep-alive,

AnyHashable("x-cache"): Missfromcloudfront,

AnyHashable("x-amzn-remapped-content-length"): 3516,

AnyHashable("Content-Type"): application/json;charset=UTF-8,

AnyHashable("Date"): Mon,

AnyHashable("x-amz-cf-id"): o2aYOoNsMY
3jqyQfcvtCsj8qitdXuHP63Jm8A1Hg1Edo-bvJxIxq9w==,

AnyHashable("x-flg-call-id"): 88aa3619167546ca8ed0304402502fq2,

AnyHashable("x-amz-cf-pop"): BOM51-C1,

AnyHashable("x-amzn-remapped-date"): Mon,  03Feb202008: 03: 44GMT,

AnyHashable("Content-Length"): 3516,

AnyHashable("Expires"): Thu,01Jan197000: 00: 00GMT,

AnyHashable("Set-Cookie"): .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=;expires=Thu,
  01Jan197000: 00: 00GMT;

path=/;samesite=lax,Identity.External=;expires=Thu,

01Jan197000: 00: 00GMT;path=/;samesite=lax,

Identity.TwoFactorUserId=;expires=Thu,

01Jan197000: 00: 00GMT;path=/;samesite=lax,

AnyHashable("x-amzn-remapped-server"): Kestrel,

AnyHashable("x-amz-apigw-id"): ,

AnyHashable("Via"): ,

AnyHashable("x-amzn-requestid"): 5c6e9360-7245-42d3-aa0c-56a6a73d286f,

AnyHashable("Cache-Control"): no-cache
]))

I am unable to find out what type of access token is it. Client has only told us that they have used Okta to encrypt the login credentials and we are unable to find out from frontend ios that what kind of mechanism have they used to encrypt the user credentials.

It does not have separated period(".") just like JWT token has.So it is something linked to open id connect and oauth using Okta. I tried searching but unable to find out such token in the URL:

https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#RFC6750

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/11/13/create-and-verify-jwts-with-node

https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-js/tree/master/packages/oidc-middleware

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/10/03/painless-node-authentication

Everywhere i can see JWT access token and not the above type of token. Could any one please help as i am using Okta for the first time using Node and Express.

Thank you for your concern in advance :)

Comment: It's something in base64 encoding. You code see what you get when you base64-decode it.

Comment: @gnasher729 it's not base64 encoding. base64 is not giving those results

Comment: It's probably NOT a JWT token, but a "regular" access token. Why do you need to decode it?

Comment: Have you tried decoding it using https://www.jsonwebtoken.io/?

Comment: @andlin , it says Token is Invalid as there are no separated periods(".") in between.This is the token we are getting from Okta Custom Service.

Comment: @andlin, they have used keychain as the mechanism to store tokens in ios. Here is the link but i am not sure how to validate and decrypt it:

https://developer.okta.com/quickstart-fragments/ios/default-example/#store-the-user-s-tokens

Comment: @PankajChibhrani It appears you can use Okta to validate the token, have you tried that? https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/validate-access-tokens/overview/ Why do you need to decrypt it?